# How does initializing inherited members inside base class constructor reduce the calls to…?

Tags: c#

I’ve read that instead of initializing inherited members ( `_c1` in our example ) inside derived constructor:

```
class A
{
    public int _c;
}

class B:A
{
    public B(int c)
    {
        _c = c;
    }
}
```

we should initialize them inside base class constructor, since that way we reduce the calls to inherited members ( `_c` ):

```
class A
{
    public A(int c)
    {
        _c = c;
    }
    public int _c;
}

class B:A
{
    public B(int c)
        : base(c)
    {


    }
}
```

If `_c` field is initialized inside base constructor, the order of initialization is the following:

1) First the field initializers of derived class `B` are called 
2) Then field initializers of base class `A` are called (at this point `_c` is set to value `0`)
3) `B’s` constructor is called, which in turn calls `A’s` custom constructor
4) `_c` field gets set to value of a parameter `c` ( inside `A’s` custom constructor )
 
5) Once `A’s` custom constructor returns, `B’s` constructor executes its code.

If `_c`  field is initialized inside `B's` constructor, the order of initialization is the following:

1) First the field initializers of a derived class `B` are called 
2) Then field initializers of a base class `A` are called(at this point `_c` is set to value `0`) 
3) `B’s` constructor is called, which in turn calls `A’s` default  constructor 
4) Once `A’s` custom constructor returns, `B’s` constructor sets `_c` field to a value of parameter `c`

As far as I can tell, in both cases was `_c` called two  times, so how exactly did we reduce calls to inherited member `_c`?

thanx

Comment: What happens when you have several derived classes? Or derived classes of the derived classes?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to say

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem starts here:

```
public int _c;
```

Fields shouldn't be public, so to do this *properly* you would have a property, and you would therefore have to call the set accessor. I think what they are trying to highlight is the difference between:

```
private int c;
public int C {get {return c;} set {this.c=value;} } // ld, ld, st
public Foo(int c) {this.c = c;} // ld, ld, st
...
Foo foo = new Foo(blah); // ld, newobj, st
```

(which does a field assignment *inside* the constructor)

vs

```
private int c;
public int C {get {return c;} set {this.c=value} } // ld, ld, st 
public Foo() {}
...
Foo foo = new Foo(); // newobj, st
foo.C = blah; // ld, ld, callvirt
```

**However!** This is all micro-optimisation. Often, trivial get/set accessors will be inlined - so there is very little difference in reality. I would happily just have:

```
public int C {get;set;}
```

Comment: I don't like the blanket statement that "fields shouldn't be public". Otherwise, this is a fine answer.

Comment: JS Bangs - ok; but public fields should be for a good, well-understood reason. Not just to save a few characters. There aren't *many* such reasons...

Comment: I’m sorry, but I can’t figure out how your reply answers my question. Anyways, in case you misunderstood my question, here’s the link to the page where author made those claims: "http://books.google.com/books?id=VGT1_UJzjM0C&lpg=PP1&dq=pro%20c%23%202008&pg=PA193#v=onepage&q&f=false" BTW -  what do ld, ld, st abbreviations stand for?

Comment: @flockofcode - IL instructs; by "ld" I mean one of the load operations (ldarg0, ldfld, etc) - st = store (set field), etc.

Comment: @flockofcode - it is *exactly* the property calls that the book refers to that I am calling out above. The fields are private; **only** the base-class can talk directly to them. Properties are actually method-pairs. To access a property involves a virtual-call. In *theory* this adds overhead, but due to JIT-inlining this is not really an overhead in most scenarios. And it *certainly* won't affect you unless your code is already super-tight.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would write class C like this:

```
class A
{
    public A(int c) : _c(c)
    {
    }
    public int _c;
}
```

And now _c is only set once.

Although in practice I think that compilers optimize this, and your last example will be as fast as this one.

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct code? I've tried it and compiler reports an error